# Coordinates are not displayed only attribute table

Tags: qgis, coordinates

I am new to QGIS and I have uploaded a second set of coordinates as a delimited text layer. I followed all the steps and the coordinates are in the same format as a previously loaded layer, but the new ones do not show up on the map and are shown as layer not supported.

[image]

Comment: Hello Katja, welcome to GIS.SE. What you screenshot shows, is most likely caused by not assigning the correct columns for the coordinates. Please try again to load the layer.

Comment: It might be that some values in the coordinate columns are not numerical.

Answer (score 3):

It seems you are loading the Delimited text as it is in the canvas. If you want to import the coordinates from the Delimited text, you should use `Add Delimited text` layer [image: 1], select the fields that have the latitudes (Y) and longitudes (X) and save the file as a shapefile or any format that you prefer.

If you want to change the coordinates from WGS 84 (the default) to any other coordinates then right-click the layer you have just created, go to Save as and select the target coordinates and save it with a new name.